# PHP Arrays from MySql Not Working

Tags: php

I have a list of keywords in the database, and I want to convert them into links.

**myTable**

```
___________________
|       myquery    |
|------------------|
|"text","more-text"|
|------------------|

<?php
$string = $row['myquery'];
$array = array($string);

foreach($array AS $result) {
    print "<a href='/" . $result . "'>" . $result . "</a>";
    // output : <a href='/"text","more-text"'>"text","more-text"</a>
}
?>
```

Why does this happen?

why the result is not `<a href='/text'>text</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you retrieve a string and you need to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it to get an array...

```
$string = $row['myquery'];
$array = explode(",", $string);

foreach($array AS $result) {
    print "<a href='/" . $result . "'>" . $result . "</a>";
}
```

The [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) function has another purpose. The docs explain the argument(s) for the `array` function:

> Syntax "index => values", separated by commas, define index and values. index may be of type string or integer. When index is omitted, an integer index is automatically generated, starting at 0. If index is an integer, next generated index will be the biggest integer index + 1. Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first.

You should probably drop the double quotes as well, i.e. `"text","more-text"` in your database should be `text,more-text`.

**UPDATE:** chris85 indicates in the comments, that [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is [also a possible solution](https://3v4l.org/vhb3q):

```
$string = $row['myquery'];
$array = str_getcsv($string);

foreach($array AS $result) {
    print "<a href='/" . $result . "'>" . $result . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Possibly, but looks like an overkill

Comment: It is simpler than explode, and safer. https://3v4l.org/vhb3q e.g. `more-text, still_one_keyword`

Comment: fair enough :))